# Order of evaluation in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, operator-precedence, r6rs

This is what works:

```
(define obj1 (maak-object (coord 1 1) #f #f #t))
(set! karaktersenobjectenlijst (append karaktersenobjectenlijst
                                  (list (list 'object obj1)))))

> (cadar karaktersenobjectenlijst)
obj1
> (positie obj1)
{1 . 1}
```

This doesn't work:

```
> (positie (cadar karaktersenobjectenlijst))
. . vector-ref: expects type <vector> as 1st argument, 
. .   given: obj1; other arguments were: 0
```

How can I make it use the value `obj1` when `(cadar karaktersobjectenlijst)` is evaluated?

Comment: What are `maak-object` and `positie`?

Comment: (define (maak-object positie blokkerend? breekbaar? water?)
    (vector object-tag positie blokkerend? breekbaar? water?))

Comment: (define (positie k)
    (cond ((karakter? k) (vector-ref k 6))
          ((object? k) (vector-ref k 1))))

Comment: Can you be more specific about the program you're writing?  There are a lot of undefined variables here: `object-tag`, `karakter?`, `coord`, `karaktersenobjectenlijst`.  Providing what seems like reasonable values for them doesn't produce results like what you're seeing.

Comment: I think those variables don't really matter, do they?

Comment: What scheme system is this? I'm most suspicious about the value that prints as 'obj1'.  Also, 'cadar' is going to select from the first element of the karaktersenobjectenlijst; if it's not empty to begin with, then the stuff you're adding makes no difference.  Sam's right; there are too many dangly bits here to make sense of this request.

Comment: @Vincent, I can't try running your program without those variables.  If they're too complicated to include here, try to provide a smaller example of your question.

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct. I have replaced your functions with some dummys and it evaluates fine:

```
(define coord cons)
(define maak-object list)
(define positie car)

(define obj1 (maak-object (coord 1 1) #f #f #t))
(define karaktersenobjectenlijst '())
(set! karaktersenobjectenlijst (append karaktersenobjectenlijst
                                       (list (list 'object obj1))))
(cadar karaktersenobjectenlijst)

(positie obj1) #-> (1 . 1)
(positie (cadar karaktersenobjectenlijst)) #-> (1 . 1)
```

The problem must be in your library code or the way you use it. The Scheme evaluation works fine.